# Songs Carlebach created from the Rosh Hashanna liturgy

Tags: song-poetry, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shlomo-carlebach

Besides Simcha Lartzecha, did Shlomo Carlebach record other songs specifically from the Rosh Hashannah liturgy? If so which ones?

Comment: Another piece of Rosh Hashanah liturgy, though said during the Ten Days of Repentance too, which he recorded is “Zachrenu Le’chaim”.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=carlebach+rosh+hashana and https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%91%D7%9A+%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9+%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V'ye'esayu Kol L'avdecha – ויאתיו כל לעבדך – which appears in the repetition of Mussaf on both days of Rosh Hashanah as well as on Yom Kippur.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7K1X72KT14) is a clip.